# Sum two numbers in SQL database

Tags: java, android, ios, database, sum

I have a program to sum two numbers and save result in SQL then show results in a `TextView` but I don't know how to make that; help me please.
But this number comes from the user (`EditText`) or from button ...
must I make a new table for the sum number for example or what .
I watch videos on you tube but I can do it that program.

this my code...

in DataBase activity :

```
public class DB_sql extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String name = "data.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME="mydata";
    public static final String KEY_First="first";
    public static final String KEY_second="second";


public DB_sql(@Nullable Context context) {
    super(context, name, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL("create table TABLE_NAME ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, KEY_First INTEGER, KEY_second INTEGER)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TABLE_NAME");
    onCreate(db);

}

public boolean insertdata (int first,int second){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues numbers = new ContentValues();
    numbers.put("first",first);
    numbers.put("second",second);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,numbers);
    if (result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

in result activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);

    result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);

    int first = getIntent().getIntExtra("number1",0);
    int second = getIntent().getIntExtra("number2",0);


    Boolean dataSQL = db_sql.insertdata(first,second);
    if (dataSQL == true){
        Toast.makeText(this,"data inserted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(this,"data not inserted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

in MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   // DB_sql db_sql = new DB_sql(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }


    public void second(View view) {
        Intent sec = new Intent(this,result.class);
        sec.putExtra("number2",40);
        startActivity(sec);
    }

    public void first(View view) {
        Intent fir=new Intent(this,result.class);
        fir.putExtra("number1",85);
        startActivity(fir);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more in detail what is not working?  Have you already checked out this: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite

Comment: I have tried many codes for this app. But app is crushed.So I wanted to know what the appropriate code . I will try these codes.. Thanks